# How can I switch the Firefox user interface to German?

Tags: firefox, language-support

I installed Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.2, setting the system language to German during the installation. However, the Firefox user interface uses English. The package `firefox-locale-de` is installed. I even set `general.useragent.locale` under `about:config` to `de-DE`, `de_DE`, and `de`, but none of these helped. How can this problem be fixed?

Comment: When you visit `about:addons` in Firefox and navigate to the "Languages" section, you should see the German language pack there (which you installed with `firefox-locale-de`). Maybe here you just still have English enabled?

Comment: What does the terminal command `locale` output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this site: https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/deutsch-de-language-pack/

you can disable or enable those packs via the firefox preferences..

[image: first screenshot with disabled german language pack]

[image: second screenshot with enabled german language pack]

Comment: When looking at the language pack list, I saw that all language packs were deactivated because of a version mismatch. I checked and saw that the Firefox version was 51.0.1, while the version of the language packs was 52.0.2. Apparently, updated language packs had been installed during the Ubuntu GNOME installation, but not the corresponding updated Firefox. Running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` fixed the problem. It is annoying that the Ubuntu GNOME installer does not install the latest package versions even when told that it should download packages during installation.

Answer (score 3):

You can set your Firefox locale to any language you want (I tried French and German specifically on Firefox 52 and Ubuntu 16.04) by following these 3 steps below.

Note that it is not necessary to also have that language installed or configured in Ubuntu's System Settings, Firefox can operate independently of that.

#### Step 1: Install language pack

Install the `firefox-locale-??` software package that corresponds to the language you want, replacing the `??` with the right locale code of course (like `firefox-locale-de` for German).

You can do this most easily by opening a terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and typing:

```
sudo apt install firefox-locale-de
```

After this, you must **restart Firefox**, otheriwse it will not notice the new language pack.

#### Step 2: Enable the language pack

Start Firefox and open the Add-On settings page (or type `about:addons` as URL). Go to the "Languages" tab of that settings page.

You should see a list of all installed Firefox language packs. Make sure the one you want is enabled. It is not necessary to disable all others, you can just leave them enabled too, or disable them, whatever you want.

Normally all newly installed language packs should be enabled by default, but it's better to double-check that.

#### Step 3: Tweak some internal configuration

Visit the advanced configuration page of your Firefox by typing `about:config` as URL in the address bar. Notice the warning and proceed.

There are two keys that we need to modify:

- `general.useragent.locale` should be set to your preferred locale's language code, like `de` for German.
- `intl.locale.matchOS` should be set to `false`. This might not be necessary if your Ubuntu system/user account's primary language is the same as the one you want in Firefox, but the browser will ignore everything you configure if this key is set to `true`.

Now you have to **restart Firefox** again, and it should come up with the new user interface language. Enjoy.